# Formalizing the use of Dirac delta in a PDF

Tags: probability, measure-theory, probability-distributions, density-function, dirac-delta

Suppose that you have a CDF $F:\mathbb{R}_+\to\mathbb{R}_+$, with only a single indifferentiability point at $x=1$, where $\lim_{z\to 1^{-} }F(z)=\frac{1}{3}$ but $F(1)=\frac{2}{3}$.  I'd like to define the PDF $f$ associated with $F$ such that $f(x)=F'(x)$ at $x\neq 1$, and $f(1)=\frac{1}{3}{\mathbf\delta}$ where ${\mathbf\delta}$ is the Dirac delta function. However, I was told that this is informal: I cannot formally define the range of $f$ to contain both $\mathbb{R}_+$ and $\{a {\mathbf \delta}: a\in \mathbb{R}_+\}$. Is my definition formal? If no, how can I make it formal? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The natural way to make this rigorous is to use measure theory.

A CDF is a way of describing the statistics of a (real-valued) random variable $X$, the idea being that $F(x) = \mathbb{P}\{X \leq x\}$.

Another way, which turns out to be equivalent, but is arguably more natural, is a (Borel) probability measure on $\mathbb{R}$.  Precisely, a (finite, positive) Borel measure $\nu$ assigns to any given Borel set $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ a number $\nu(A) \in [0,\infty)$.  (Think of a Borel set as a "nice" subset of $\mathbb{R}$, or one that can be built out of intervals.  Intervals are Borel sets.)  It is a probability measure if $\nu(\mathbb{R}) = 1$.  For us, the idea is $\nu(A) = \mathbb{P}\{X \in A\}$, that is, $\nu$ is a more vivid description of $X$.

It is a theorem of Lebesgue-Stieltjes integration that there is a one-to-one correspondence between Borel probability measures and CDFs through the map $\nu \mapsto F^{\nu}$ given by $F^{\nu}(x) = \nu((-\infty,x])$.  Hence anytime you work with a CDF, there is also an associated probability measure $\nu$.

You can think of $\nu$ as being the "derivative" of $F^{\nu}$ (or $F^{\nu}$ being the "anti-derivative" of $\nu$).  The relevance to your question: this makes sense whether or not $F^{\nu}$ is differentiable in the usual sense.

For example, if $F^{\nu}$ is differentiable at every point in $\mathbb{R}$ and $(F^{\nu})' = f$, then $\nu$ is given (by Lebesgue integration) through the formula:
\begin{equation*}
\nu(A) = \int_{A} f(x) \, dx.
\end{equation*}
A shorthand way to write this is $\nu = f(x) \, dx$ (hence, almost literally,
$\nu$ is the derivative of $F^{\nu}$).

As in your example, there is no reason $F^{\nu}$ should be differentiable.  Basically, your question seems to be: what replaces the decomposition $\nu = f(x) \, dx$ in general?

The Lebesgue Decomposition Theorem says that, given a probability measure $\nu$, there is a function $f$ and a singular measure $\nu^{s}$ such that
\begin{equation*}
\nu = f(x) \, dx + \nu^{s}.
\end{equation*}
The sum is interpreted "set-wise" (that is, pointwise) as $\nu(A) = \int_{A} f(x) \, dx + \nu^{s}(A)$.  The measure $\nu^{s}$ is singular: you can think of that as meaning it does not match our intuition about densities.

In your example, $F = F^{\nu}$ for the probability measure $\nu$ given by
\begin{equation*}
\nu(A) = \int_{A} F'(x) \, dx + \frac{1}{3} \delta_{1}(A)
\end{equation*}
where $\delta_{1}$ is the measure defined by
\begin{equation*}
\delta_{1}(A) = \left\{ \begin{array}{r l}
1, & \text{if} \, \, 1 \in A \\
0, & \text{otherwise}
\end{array} \right.
\end{equation*}
We call $\delta_{1}$ the Dirac mass at $1$; for an arbitrary $x \in \mathbb{R}$, $\delta_{x}$ is defined analogously.

More often than not, $\nu^{s}$ looks something like the previous example (or, as you say, it is a sum of finitely many Dirac deltas).  In most applications, there is are sequences $\{x_{n}\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ and $\{p_{n}\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \subseteq [0,1]$ with $\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} p_{n} < 1$ such that
\begin{equation*}
\nu^{s}(A) = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} p_{n} \delta_{x_{n}}(A) = \sum_{x_{n} \in A} p_{n}
\end{equation*}
(It is worth noting that if $\nu^{s}$ is a probability measure, or $f = 0$ above, then $\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} p_{n} = 1$ and $\nu^{s}$ is precisely the probability measure describing a discrete random variable with PMF $\{p_{n}\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$.  Hence what we are doing unifies "continuous" and "discrete" RV and PDFs and PMFs.)

However, the singular measure $\nu^{s}$ can also have a "continuous" part: for example, it is possible that $\nu^{s}(\{x\}) = 0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ (so it has no Dirac parts), but still it cannot be represented using a density.  Usually, you won't see such measures unless you are asking about long-time behavior of a stochastic process or an iterative procedure.  For example, if $X_{n} \in [0,1]$ is a RV whose ternary expansion up to order $n$ is equally likely to be any string consisting of $0$'s and $2$'s, but no $1$'s, then $X_{n} \overset{d}{\to} \tilde{X}$, where $\tilde{X}$ is described by such a singular probability measure that cannot be described using Dirac masses.  $\tilde{X}$ is the RV in $[0,1]$ whose ternary expansion is equally likely to have a $0$ or a $2$ at any given digit, but never has a $1$; its CDF is the "Devil's Staircase" or Cantor function.  (Interestingly, the Cantor function has derivative zero at "most" points, yet it remains a CDF.)

Comment: Thanks. I understand the intuition, my question is about formalization. For example, there is a notion that I have seen "generalized probability density" functions or "generalized functions " (for example, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_function) I'm basically looking for a formal notion that I can refer to..

Comment: Rather than "generalized function," I would start by saying that the Dirac delta function is a "measure."  Everything you need (for understanding CDFs, their densities, and what happens when density doesn't make sense) is covered by the theory of Lebesgue-Stieltjes measures.  (If you have seen Riemann-Stieltjes integrals, Lebesgue-Stieltjes measures are the mathematical objects underlying those.)

Comment: Thanks a lot, that helps. I have one question left: why can't we define ("generalized") PDFs to have a range $\mathbb{R}\cup \{a \delta | a\in \mathbb{R}\}$ and define integration on them? Extending the set of real numbers like that seems like a natural idea..